# Selecting object from different namespace at run timein c#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is it possible to select a namespace for classes at runtime. We have two copies of auto generated objects in different namespaces. Here is an example:

```
Namespace1
    ClassA
    ClassB

Namaspace2
    ClassA
    ClassB
```

Formerly, the code is simple like below

```
using Namespace1
...
    ClassA.AMethod()
```

However, we need to select namespace at runtime using a condition variable. Is there a way to define a GetNamespace() method and use it like below or is there any other way you recommend?

```
GetNamespace().ClassA.AMethod()
```

Cheers,
Burak

Comment: You say these classes are auto-generated. Is it possible to modify this generation so that each of these classes inherit from a common base class or implement a common interface (e.g have both ClassAs derive from ClassABase)? If so, you may be able to write your code using the base class/interface. The remaining challenge then is object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to dynamically select the namespace, but I think you're in the perfect situation to use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). To do so, all your A classes must derive from an abstract one:

```
namespace Common {

public abstract class AbsA
{
    //...
}

public class MyFactory
{
    public MyFactory()
    {
        //...
    }

    public AbsA getA()
    {
        AbsA a;
        if (condition)
            a = new Namespace1.A();
        else
            a = new Namespace2.A();
        return a;
    }
}

}
```

Then you ask your factory for object creation:

```
MyFactory factory = new MyFactory();
labelMessage.Text = factory.getA().Something;
```

This complicates your structure a bit, but also makes it more coherent.

Comment: Thanks. Before creating a factory, as an inexperienced c# programmer, I hoped that there may be a simple solution but it seems there is not.

Answer (score 1):

Two types from different namespaces are *entirely* different types as far as the CLR is concerned. Basically you'd need to consider the same solutions as you would for picking between any other arbitrary types... e.g. making both classes implement the same interface, and instead of `GetNamespace()` returning a namespace, it would have to return the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can:

```
var type = Type.GetType("Namespace1.ClassA");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

If you then want to invoke methods on that instance, you need to either cast it to a common interface, or get a `MethodInfo` instance to invoke.  If you control the generation of the classes, I would recommend the interface approach:

```
public interface IClassA
{
    void AMethod();
}

namespace Namespace1
{
    public class ClassA : IClassA
    { /* Stuff... */ }
}
```

That way, you need only:

```
var type = Type.GetType("Namespace1.ClassA");
IClassA instance = (IClassA)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

instance.AMethod();
```

Most autogenerated classes using tools such as Linq-to-Sql, Entity Framework, and even WCF proxies are created as `partial`, which means you can create an additional file, e.g. `ClassA.partial.cs` and add more to your class declarations without modifying the auto-generated class:

```
partial class ClassA : IClassA { }
```